# Change the status of blocks on the basis of id in mapSVG

Tags: php, jquery, mapsvg

I am new to mapSVG. I am using onclick event on the blocks of the svg files. On click I want to change the status of blocks selected/unselected of all the other blocks. I have the id of all the blocks dynamically. How can I use the id of block to change their status select/unselect.

Comment: Please share your HTML and JS code. Otherwise nobody can help you.

Comment: I am using this link as a refrence. My code is exactly the same provided in this link. http://mapsvg.com/_documentation.html